# React-native pick images from gallery like instagram

Tags: react-native, show, image-gallery

I want to load images from gallery like instagram as below, how i can do that.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use npm like `react-thumbnail-gallery`

[Npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-thumbnail-gallery)

[Demo link](https://johnwatkins0.github.io/react-thumbnail-gallery/example/)